# Can we do screen sharing using UCWA API (Lync) and Voice call?

Tags: ucwa

Can we do the following UCWA API (Lync)?

1. Screen Sharing
2. Video Call
3. Voice Call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands today, No, No and No.